# Does XamlReader.Parse() work differently from a BackgroundWorker thread?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am retrieving a xaml string from a database and constructing a xaml canvas.

The call

```
 loadedCanvas = (Canvas)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xamlTemplate);
```

works fine from the UI thread.  When I try to do the same thing from a BackgroundWorker thread I get a XamlParseException with the message 'Cannot create unkown type Canvas' pointing to the first Canvas tag.

The xaml is the same in both cases.

I get the feeling that I'm missing something blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 'm not sure why you are getting the specific error message (which is misleading), but you cannot load XAML from a non-UI thread; even if you could, you would then be unable to use them from your UI thread because WPF controls have thread affinity.

The reason you cannot load from non-UI (technically the restriction is "non-STA thread") is that UI elements require the current thread to be STA for marshalling purposes and will throw an exception to that effect if you are currently inside a MTA thread. The managed thread pool, which `BackgroundWorker` uses, has only MTA threads.

TL;DR: You need to do this from within your UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it makes perfect sense. It _was_ blindingly obvious after all ;)